# Return a string if row id doesnt exist

Tags: android, sqlite

Here i have method to get the status of a person based on its id_number/number from the table. If person number exist it will return its status like `PENDING` or `ACCEPTED`.

However it number does not exist it should return string of `NONE` instead. The code works only if number exist but it returns ArrayIndexOutOfBounds if number does not exist;

How can i prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` so that if the number does not exist it will return to a value of string `NONE`.

```
   public String getStatus(int number) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new Sting[] {KEY_NUMBER,
              KEY_FULLNAME, KEY_STATUS}, KEY_NUMBER + "=?", 
               new String[] {String.valueOf(number)}, null, null, null, null);

         if(cursor != null) {
           cursor.moveToFirst();

           String status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("remark");
           return status;
         }
    }
```

i call the method something like this;

```
  String text =  db.getStatus(100); 
   if(text.equals(null){
      Log.e("Null: ", "null");
   } else
       Log.e("exist", "exist");
```

if this number doesnt exist it will crash and logcat shows `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public abstract boolean moveToFirst ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Move the cursor to the first row.
>
> This method will return false if the cursor is empty.
>
> Returns whether the move succeeded.

You are not making use of the return value of  [moveToFirst()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst())

BTW, It's better to return null than an explicit string valued "NONE" because the comparison with null is quicker. Your code should change as

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
       String status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("remark");
       return status;
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the `Cursor` has returned any rows. You can do this by checking `cursor.getCount() > 0`, or if you need to iterate through the `Cursor` you can do the following:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
  //Do your code
  return "Something";
}
return "NONE";
```